# Informix - concatenating data contained in same column based on id

Tags: tags, concatenation, informix

I have a need to concatenate strings in the same field based on id in Informix.  I realize this can be done easily in MSSQL.

Here is an example of my current table:

```
id | doc_num | page_num | description
-------------------------------------------------
1  |  1      |    1     | This is the story about
1  |  1      |    2     | a girl named Daisy.    
1  |  2      |    1     | Daisy had a dog named
1  |  2      |    2     | Rover.
2  |  1      |    1     | This story is about Bob.
2  |  2      |    1     | Bob is a DBA who works
2  |  2      |    2     | at an important company
2  |  2      |    3     | that develops important
2  |  2      |    4     | software.
```

Desired output:

```
id |  description
------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  This is a story about a girl named Daisy.
   |  Daisy has a dog named Rover.
------------------------------------------------------------   
2  |  This story is about Bob.  Bob is a DB who works at an
   |  important company that develops important software.
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and well done on resolving your problem by research on DBA Stack Exchange.  It would be sensible if "it can be done easily in MS SQL" to show how you'd do it there — it might guide people into advising you on the right way to do it in Informix, too.  Also, mentioning version numbers and platforms can be helpful — for any DBMS.  (For Informix, at minimum say "Informix 12.10 on Windows", for example.  Sometimes, it needs to be more specific than that; it is preferable to say "Informix 12.10.FC9".)  Often, you'll get better/quicker help adding the [tag:sql] tag.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65101/multiple-table-rows-in-one-row-informix

Since I am running Informix 12, it works using rank() over() sys_connect_by_path().